# Registration timer expired, but client is still registering! - Google geocoding error

Tags: iphone, xcode, google-api, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I am trying to use these two lines to get lat/long info when given an address input.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv", theAddress];

NSString *locationString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
```

It is weird that sometimes I get the lat, long info as quick as in 5 seconds and in other cases the app is stuck for about 5 mins and then it logs an error stating "Registration timer expired, but client is still registering!"

It also gives the location info (ie result string wth lat/long info) as null.

I tried it a number of times and couldn't figure out what makes it work and what doesn't.

Has anybody encountered the same issue before or any advice on this pls.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try below code its working fine with me.

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coord=[self gettingLatandLonFromAddress:address];

  -(CLLocationCoordinate2D ) gettingLatandLonFromAddress:(NSString *)address
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D currentLoc;
        NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[address stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        NSString *locationString=[NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
        double latitude=0.0;
        double longitude=0.0;
        if([listItems count] >=4  && [ [listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"]){
            latitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
            longitude = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
        }
        else{       
            NSLog(@"Error");        
        }

        currentLoc.latitude=latitude;
        currentLoc.longitude=longitude;
        return currentLoc;
    }
```

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the reply.. But I am getting build errors when I tried using your code. I am not sure if I am using it correctly though. I include this in viewdidLoad method - CLLocationCoordinate2D coord=[self gettingLatandLonFromAddress:address]; and call the function below. But it gives me build errors saying "error: Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'CLLocationCoordinate2D' from incompatible type 'id'". I am pretty new to this. So can u pls tell me where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: have you imported #import<CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

Comment: i think we cann't assign values directly. so declare first CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;  then call that method like   coord=[self gettingLatandLonFromAddress:address];

Comment: Hey.. Thanks for the reply.. I got it working.. Just now figured, what my problem is. Actually the code (Both urs and mine) works fine with simulator but doesn't pick it up in a device. This is completely strange and weird. Did u have any such issues when doing. In a simulator, it gives me back the result in 5v seconds, but in a device it actually hangs up the app for about 3 to 5 mins and gets a   null location string. So weird! I could test all other location based applications in my device. But cant get this working. Any ideas on this?

Comment: And I am using an iPod touch (4th generation) to test the application. I believe this should not make any difference though?

Comment: i m using above code in app.while saving location details in db.if lat/lon is given by user and address in given .by above code i get lat/lon and store in db.in home screen i shown location like annotation (getting current lat/lon) its showing current place.lets any way i will check it now

Comment: its not difference...lets any way i will check it with device now